# Why is a new branch in our github repo unavailable for checkout?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout

A colleague created a new branch in our repo in Github, but I cannot seem to use checkout to get it, and when I do a `git branch -a` (using Git Bash, Windows 10) it is not listed among the branches.  Yet in my Github account behold, there it is under Active branches: 36_assistapi.

I tried several variations on the following command but get the same output.

```
$ git checkout origin/36_assistapi
error: pathspec 'origin/36_assistapi' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I also tried `git checkout 36_assistapi` and `git checkout 36_assistapi`
Surely we've omitted something simple:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to fetch the repo so you get a local copy of this new branch:

```
git fetch origin
```

Once you do this, you should be able to check out to it:

```
git checkout 36_assistapi
```